# Chromebook - screen goes black when launching unity

Tags: boot, chromebook, wayland, crouton

My Chromebook's screen goes black when trying to launch Ubuntu. This is what it says:

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 7 03:27:09 PST 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 3584000 verity payload=PARTUUID=8f7f09fd-3fa9-c04b-8582-dd9473131ef9/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=8f7f09fd-3fa9-c04b-8582-dd9473131ef9/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=3584000 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=8ee125e1ad6990685678c87e3d115879675b76d9 salt=8f3445403bb16efc755979d0ee0f4c1133bf124b16ff7af09d6e3890c24ac050" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=8f7f09fd-3fa9-c04b-8582-dd9473131ef9 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic i915.enable_psr=1  
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:59:06PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.11 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.2.log", Time: Mon Nov 13 09:39:31 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
crouton: version 1-20171109145451~master:35a16889
release: trusty
architecture: amd64
xmethod: xorg
targets: xorg,xiwi,unity,extension
host: version 10106.0.0 (Official Build) dev-channel samus 
kernel: Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 7 03:27:09 PST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
freon: yes
Another instance of croutonclip running, waiting...
Another instance of croutontriggerd running, waiting...
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "TakeDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist
```

Also, when I run: `sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n trusty -u`
I get the following message:

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n trusty -u
/usr/local/chroots/trusty already exists; updating it...
Preparing chroot environment...
awk: run time error: 'system' function not allowed in sandbox mode
        FILENAME="/tmp/crouton.TEu/installer/prepare.sh" FNR=25 NR=25
Installing brightness into the chroot...
Installing croutonpowerd into the chroot...
awk: run time error: 'system' function not allowed in sandbox mode
        FILENAME="/tmp/crouton.TEu/chroot-bin/croutonpowerd" FNR=25 NR=25
Installing croutonversion into the chroot...
Installing host-dbus into the chroot...
Installing host-wayland into the chroot...
awk: run time error: redirection not allowed in sandbox mode
        FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0
```

!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all current downloads. First, find the name of your chroot with

```
cd /usr/local/chroots
```

then use

```
sudo delete-chroot chrootname
```

Then reinstall crouton and try to run it again. Long process, but it should work.